# Quantum Mechanics - Prove that the permutation operators do not commute in general

Tags: quantum-mechanics, identical-particles

Previously, in my Quantum Mechanics exam,

We have asked to **"Prove that the permutation operators do not commute in general."**

And I have answered it as follows

[image]

But **my teacher marked it as the wrong proof.**

And told me to prove for indices 1,2,3,4
i.e. **P(12)P(34) not equal to P(34)P(12)**

**Is it acceptable to just prove for indices (1,2,3,4) if we have asked to prove this question in general?**

I have this argument with my teacher.

Please clarify!

Thank You

Comment: Actually, $P_{12}$ and $P_{34}$ do commute as they have no common indices.  On the other hand, $P_{12}$ and $P_{23}$ do not.   Your proof would work for any pairs of indices and is certainly wrong in general, although for $S_3$ no pairs of transpositions commute.

Comment: But my proof has a common index "i" then why is it wrong?

Comment: Oh! yes it’s difficult to read yes I see.  I dunno what’s wrong then, although I will point out we don’t check work here.

Comment: It looks to me that you are misusing the operators $P_{ij}$. $P_{ij}$ ought to swap the quantum numbers between particles $i$ and $j$, but you are using it to swap the coordinates labeled $i$ and $j$. In other words, $P_{12} P_{13} \psi(\gamma_1 \gamma_2 \gamma_3) = P_{12} \psi(\gamma_3 \gamma_2 \gamma_1) = \psi(\gamma_2 \gamma_3 \gamma_1)$, not $\psi(\gamma_3, \gamma_1, \gamma_2)$.